# How to apply cut and sed commands to Powershell?

Tags: bash, powershell, unix, sed, cut

I have a bash script which retrieves data from 2 separate files (1 for user data and another for default text) and outputs a circular letter:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Please enter two parameters"
    exit
elif [ $# -eq 1 ]
then 
    echo "Please enter one more parameter"
    exit
elif [ $# -gt 2 ]
then 
    echo "Please enter ONLY two parameters"
    exit
fi


while read line
do 

    iN=`echo $line | cut -f1 -d";"`
    iA=`echo $line | cut -f2 -d";"`
    iD=`echo $line | cut -f3 -d";"`

cat $2|sed "s/<NAME>/$iN/g" | sed "s/<ADDRESS>/iA/g" | sed "s/<DATE>/$iD/g"

done < data
```

It needs to be converted to a PS script, here's what I could've done so far:

```
if ($# -eq 0) {
    Write-Output "Please enter two parameters"
} elseif ($# -eq 1 ) {
    Write-Output "Please enter one more parameter"
} elseif ($# -gt 2) {
    Write-Output "Please enter ONLY two parameters"
}


foreach($line in Get-Content .\data.txt) {
    
}
```

I wasn't able to find any equivalent of `sed` or `cut` commands on the internet so I'd appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: take a look at `Read-Host` for getting user input. then look at parsing the input ... or [better] ask for each input on its own so there is no need to count things. [*grin*]

Comment: You will need to use `split` and `replace` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unix Utils for Windows set that has all these commands converted, and we have been using them for a long time in production with no issues.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/

It has most of them: sed, cut, cat etc.